# Does SEO ranking based on domain apply to domains with forwarding?

Tags: seo, domains, multiple-domains

Lets say I have a site at "myrandomdomain.com". I want to target a keyword "my keyword" and so I buy "mykeyword.com". Can I still have the keyword benefits of having mykeyword.com when it just forwards to myrandomdomain.com? The domain would not be masked. My guess would have been no but SEO Moz seems a bit unclear about it:

> A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of
>   link juice (ranking power) to the redirected page.

I'd just like to make sure before I switch my site over. If it would have the same effect to forward it I'll just do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 301 redirect passing juice is not exactly what you are thinking. Too many people take that as a blanket statement without regard to the criteria associated with it. 301 redirects are clearly to avoided if possible and not used as an SEO tactic. 301 redirects are a necessity to be use sparingly and as necessary.

Having said that, if your old site is not that old, then there may no harm in transferring your site to the new domain name if you want to. There would be a settling process that can take 30-60 days or more. If your old site has been around for a while, then I would think the pay-off would be far too little. The truth is, while keywords in domain names are clues to Google and Bing, they do not offer much if any added weight in regards to SEO. If your old site has settled into Google and Bing, then I would think you can rank just as well without making changes.